# Is 直美 a traditional Japanese name?

Tags: names

I was surprised to learn that 直美 isn't spelled out using katakana and, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naomi_(given_name)#Japanese):

> Naomi (なおみ, ナオミ), pronounced [naomi] is a Japanese name. Though it is a unisex name, it is primarily used by women. Naomi can be spelled using hiragana, katakana, kanji, or a combination of kana and kanji. For example;
>
> - なお美
> - ナオ美
> - 直美
> - 尚美
> - 直己
> - 尚己
> - 直実
> - 尚実
> - 奈緒美

...my question is, did the Japanese name predate (or develop separately from) the Western name? Is this just a coincidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably just a coincidence. The "Western" name appears to be of Hebrew origin, whereas in Japanese なお *nao* is a common unit that combines with suffixes like 子 *ko* (Naoko) or 美 *mi* (Naomi) indicating a female given name.

Comment: ん？「なおみ」ってもともとは外国の名前で、日本では谷崎潤一郎の『痴人の愛』以降に使われるようになったって聞いた覚えが。。

Comment: @Chocolate え〜 面白い！